# Using if statement with sqlite data reader

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I have a SQLite DB for a Check Book app. The TXDataTABLE has a number of field the two I am concerned with are txSortDate & txSearchMonth. I have written a SQL search to find all entries from one month to another month by year. The search works but the READER has other ideas how it wants to display the data.

**EXAMPLE** if I set the from month to Jan and the to month to Mar, I get the corresponding months but the reader includes the current month.

Here is the SQL search code:

```
  ElseIf gvSearchType = "MoRangeYr" Then
       cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txSearchMonth BETWEEN $gvFromMonth AND $gvToMonth AND txYear = $gvYear "
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvFromMonth", gvFromMonth)
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvToMonth", gvToMonth)
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvYear", gvYear)
```

Here is the READER Code
DB in NOT bound to the DataGridView that displays the data

```
                Using rdr As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                'dgvTX.DataSource = rdr
                'Statement Above is when DB is bound to dgvTX
                '============================================

                While rdr.Read()
                    intID = CInt((rdr("TID")))
                    strDate = rdr("txSortDate").ToString 'txSearchMonth '
                    strTxType = rdr("txType").ToString
                    strAmt = CDec(rdr("txAmount"))
                    strCKNum = rdr("txCKNum").ToString
                    strDesc = rdr("txDesc").ToString
                    strBal = CDec(rdr("txBalance"))
                    dgvTX.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"
                    dgvTX.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"
                    'dgvTX.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C"'Adds the $ sign and commas
                    dgvTX.Rows.Add(intID, strDate, strTxType, strAmt, strCKNum, strDesc, strBal, emptyStr)

                    rowCount = rowCount + 1

                End While
```

The offending line of code is

```
 strDate = rdr("txSortDate").ToString
```

What I see as a solution is a conditional statement in the READER code.

OR I have two readers one for other search and one for the MoRangeYr.

I would like some help writing the conditional statement?

OR other better suggestions how to solve this

- Data in the txSortDate looks like this Oct-23-2021
- Data in the txSearchMonth looks like this 1,2,3 you get the idea

YES I was not thinking when I designed the DB the old saying hind site is always 20/20

Here is a screen shot of a search for Jan to Mar NOTE I did not ask for OCT
[image: Error]

The search data for From & To Months are entered using a combobox
partial code below

```
Private Sub cbToMo_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbToMo.SelectedIndexChanged

    If cbToMo.SelectedIndex > -1 Then

        Dim sitem As String
        sitem = CType(cbToMo.SelectedItem, String)

        Dim month As String
        month = sitem
        Select Case month
            Case = "January"
                intToMonth = 1
            Case = "February"
                intToMonth = 2
            Case = "March"
                intToMonth = 3
```

Comment: Your last comments I interpret, that you solved it yourself? Otherwise I cannot understand your text properly, please better list some data returned by your code and its according records in the table - like it is appreciated here in stackoverflow.

Comment: Don't use BETWEEN to check date ranges. Check the column date is >= the first moment of the range, and < (not <=) the first moment after the range ends.

Comment: @BitLauncher No I did not solve the issue as I do not know how to use a conditional statement in the READER code block nor I am not sure that is the best solution to the problem Please see screen shot I did not request Oct data

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn I had the code written as you suggested the issue continued with searching Jan to Mar I still was getting Oct which is why I began to look at the READER as the issue

Comment: Please add the values for columns txSearchMonth and txYear, they are used in your select statement, therefore relevant to get all the needed information to solve it.

Comment: @BitLauncher Added the code that gathers the From & To Months

Comment: Additional remark: Date (is column txSortDate?) has a strange format. I never seen this before. Please use a worldwide known format as e. g. ISO8601. You can find it e. g. in Wikipedia, e. g. 2023-03-26

Comment: @Vector: please extend the table/screenshot with the values from columns txSearchMonth and txYear - and the column "Date" in the screenshot is "txSortDate"?

Comment: @BitLauncher The Search Data is entered on another form and sent to the call made by a button named SEARCH here is a gift      Dim dateToday = Date.Today
 Dim lblDate As String = dateToday.ToString("MMM" & " " & "d" & " " & "yyyy")

Comment: @Vector Ah, you made this a varchar/text column. Text columns don't care if the values inside them look like dates or numbers: they do a text match only. And since October is month 10, the first character `1` sorts before the `9` from September or the `8` from August, and that's where the comparison stops. Your best option is to _rewrite all the data_. As painful as that sounds, it really will be easier. On most platforms I'd recommend a real date value using a data type from the DateTime family. Sqlite doesn't have this, so you should use `yyyy-MM-dd` (ISO8601)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn YEP all the DB col are text BAD database design on my part Just tested June to Aug and it works as intended WHY June, July and Aug have no 1 in the date I have been learning C# so perhaps a complete rewrite is in order Thanks for taking the time to provide good advice See you here a lot

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn SAID best option "rewrite all the data" NOT sure that is what I did but I used these four sql statements in this order ALTER TABLE TxData ADD NxData INTEGER

UPDATE TxData SET NxData = txSearchMonth

ALTER TABLE TxData DROP COLUMN txSearchMonth

ALTER TABLE TxData RENAME COLUMN NxData to txSearchMonth
by making NxData a INTEGER the search works as desired. If this is what you would call rewrite all the data I might call it redefine the variables from TEXT to INTEGERS There is always two ways to do things if you THINK long enough wrote a test app because I was chicken cluck

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your date from `String` to a `Date` type:

```
Dim dateFormat = "MMM-d-yyyy"
Dim dteDate As Date 
Date.TryParseExact(rdr("txSortDate").ToString, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, dteDate)
```

Then use `dteDate` in your grid.

(Though I agree with `@Joel Coehoorn` that the best option is to rewrite your data)

Comment: let me test your answer YES Joel Coehoorn suggestion while painful is correct Thanks